# Apache module in c, Getting error when i start the apache server

Tags: c, apache2

I have written a apache module in C ,through which to retieve the POST form value from browser. my module is compiled successfully,then load the module but when i start the apache server ,it throws a error

> apache2: Syntax error on line 204 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dumpost.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dumpost.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dumpost.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Anybody figure out and suggest me.....

Comment: What did you check already?

Comment: It looks as if `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dumpost.so` is not around or at least the Apache does not hve the rights to access it.

Comment: I am using apache 2.2 and compile with apxs2 -c and after load,conf the file .But i donot know why .so file not created ? so when i start apache it throws error.....

Comment: First make sure that the file is actually where Apache is looking for it, if it is then check the file permissions to make sure the file is readable and possibly executable. If all looks okay, is Apache compiled as a 32-bit application and your module in 64-bit mode, or the other way around?